# Can I clamp singular values of $3\times3$ matrix without effectively computing SVD?

Tags: optimization, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have a $3\times3$ matrix $A$, and compute its SVD $U \Sigma V^\star = A$.

I clamp the singular values in $\Sigma$ to some small range (e.g. $[0.5, 1.5]$ ) and reconstruct matrix $\widetilde{A}=U \widetilde{\Sigma} V^\star$ with clamped singular values. I keep $Det(U), Det(V) \ge 0$, so any mirroring comes across as negative singular values.

For example (in 2D, to simplify) if $A=U \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \end{array} \right)V^\star$, then I need to find the matrix $\widetilde{A}=U \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
.5 & 0 \\
0 & 1.5 \end{array} \right) V^\star$. Note that I don't need to know $U$ or $V$. Also, if I clamp approximately, e.g. to $\widetilde{A}=U \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
.6 & 0 \\
0 & 1.4 \end{array} \right) V^\star$, that's fine, too.

Is there some way to do this (perhaps approximately) that is numerically cheaper than computing SVD? Is there a way to do this for $2\times2$ matrix?

Comment: Hello. I am not sure what you mean with clamp. You can use the power method to find the largest eigenvalue of a matrix. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration then you will get both a vector and the eigenvalue. But it is a kind of simple method so maybe you already know of it.

Comment: Hi, 
Right, that's not exactly my problem. I added an example to the question.
By clamping, I mean finding the closest value in the range. E.g. -1 gets clamped to 0.5 (closest in the range [0.5;1.5]), +2 gets clamped to 1.5, 1 gets clamped to 1 (which is itself in the range). 
My problem is solved perfectly by SVD. I'm looking for something that solves it maybe approximately, but cheaper (in less operations)

Comment: You don't seem to be talking about eigenvalues, but rather singular values, which are only related in a simple way to eigenvalues in the symmetric case.

Comment: I updated the question, thanks for pointing this out!
Silly me didn't realize there's a difference. I can reformulate my problem as symmetric (although it'll cost me some performance), so if you know of a way to quickly clamp singular values or eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix, please share!